# MUI: customize button component with tailwind classes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to customise the look of MUI's `<Button />` component. As i want to do it by using `tailwind` classes i tried to use `defaultProps` instead of `styleOverrides`.

```js
const lightTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: { defaultProps: { classes: { root: 'p-8' } } },
  },
});
```

It is working fine except that i'm not able to add `tailwind` classes when i use the `<Button />` component as this will overwrite the changes i made above.

```js
<Button variant="contained" classes={{ root: 'p-12' }}>
  Ok
</Button>
```

Is there a way to extend the definition of the `classes` prop rather than overwriting it?

Comment: I don't think this can work the way you want it to work. `defaultProps` are all overridable. You must instead place your extra tailwind classes in `className`. It will still not work perfectly, which is expected – Mui and TW step on each other's toes. I would pick one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend the classes without overwriting them, you can use a utility like [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) to combine the classes from defaultProps and your custom classes.

Here's how you can achieve it:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import clsx from 'clsx';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      defaultProps: {
        classes: { root: 'p-8' },
      },
    },
  },
});

function CustomButton() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        classes={{
          root: clsx('p-12', theme.components.MuiButton.defaultProps.classes.root),
        }}
      >
        Ok
      </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default CustomButton;
```

Check [image: Edit festive-glade-6ztkt9]